# glDrawArrays Crashes When Using Texture Coordinates

Tags: opengl, exc-bad-access, vbo

So I've implemented a really quick VBO just to see if its worth switching from display lists. I've ran into a bit of trouble though when I try to put in texture coordinates. It crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS with glDrawArrays. Im pretty sure its the way Im rendering the VBO's, specifically in the order that Im doing it, but I've tried just about everything and haven't been able to get it to work properly. Here is my code:

```
//create a vertex buffer object for the particles to use
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    //create the data, this is really sloppy
    float QuadVertextData[] = {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0};
    float QuadTextureData[] = {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0};

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*4*3, &QuadVertextData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //generate another buffer for the texcoords
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBOT);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOT);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*4*2, &QuadTextureData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

The rendering code:

```
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOT);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

From what I've seen on the internet, Im not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Do the values you're getting for `VBO` and `VBOT` look like valid object ids? Have you tried calling `glGetError()` to see if any errors are flagged?

Comment: @RetoKoradi as far as I know glGetError only works after it would be called. I can also render the vertices just fine, it's the texcoords that's the problem.

Comment: I tried your code, and it works fine for me. I suspect that the problem is something outside the code we're seeing here.

Comment: @RetoKoradi that's all the code that I've implemented for the VBOs, unless of course you count the declarations for the functions and the GLuints.

Comment: All I did was drop it into very minimal GLUT app on a Mac, declared `VBO` and `VBOT` as `GLuint`, and added a `glClear()` call at the start of the render function. No crash, and it even rendered the white square. I really can't think of a reason why it would crash for you.

Comment: @RetoKoradi then what could possibly be causing this? Could it be my graphics card even?

Comment: @BlueSpud: It is really hard to tell. If your full code is just the above and a little bit of boilerplate, you could simply post the full code, so we could check if there is some mistake in there. The parts you posted so far are absolutely correct, assuming you use a legacy GL context or a compatibility profile.

Comment: @RetoKoradi it turns out that if I use a shader or a texture other than the 0 texture, it just crashes. No idea why, but Im going to look into it and probably make a new question, as this one isn't really appropriate. Thanks for your help.